# Retrieving data from a MYSQL table instead of a .csv file with angular 'select'

Tags: mysql, angularjs

My WebApp displays a radar from data stored in a .cvs file. Instead, I'd like to get the data from a mysql table.

Here is the HTML/PHP code that selects the .csv file as a source of data:

```
<body class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl as radar">   
    <!-- START VIZ-->
    <div class="visualization col-xs-7">
    <p>Select other sources:
    <select ng-options="example for example in radar.examples" ng-model="radar.exampleSelected" ng-change="radar.selectExample(radar.exampleSelected)"></select>
    </p>
    <div class="visualization">
    <radar csv="radar.csv" config="radar.config"></radar>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF VIZ-->
</body>
```

The HTML/PHP file calls these files at the end:

```
 <!-- scripts -->
      <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
      <script src="radar.js"></script>
      <script src="radarDraw.js"></script>
      <script>
<!-- end scripts -->
```

Below is the content of a file called 'app.js':

```
(function() {
  angular.module("RadarChart", [])
    .directive("radar", radar)
    .directive("onReadFile", onReadFile)
    .controller("MainCtrl", MainCtrl);

  // controller function MainCtrl
  function MainCtrl($http) {
    var ctrl = this;
    init();


    // function init
    function init() {
      // initialize controller variables
      ctrl.examples = [
         "radar-data.csv",
         "data_plant_seasons.csv",
        "data_car_ratings.csv"
      ];
      ctrl.exampleSelected = ctrl.examples[0];
      ctrl.getData = getData;
      ctrl.selectExample = selectExample;

      // initialize controller functions
      ctrl.selectExample(ctrl.exampleSelected);
      ctrl.config = {
        w: 300,
        h: 300,
        facet: false,
        levels: 5,
        levelScale: 0.85,
        [ETC...]
      };
    }

    // function getData
    function getData($fileContent) {
      ctrl.csv = $fileContent;
    }

    // function selectExample
    function selectExample(item) {
      var file = item ; //+ ".csv";
      $http.get(file).success(function(data) {
        ctrl.csv = data;
      });
    }
  }

  // directive function sunburst
  function radar() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {
        csv: "=",
        config: "="
      },
      link: radarDraw
    };
  }


  // directive function onReadFile
  function onReadFile($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: false,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var fn = $parse(attrs.onReadFile);
        element.on("change", function(onChangeEvent) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(onLoadEvent) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
              fn(scope, {
                $fileContent: onLoadEvent.target.result
              });
            });
          };
          reader.readAsText((onChangeEvent.srcElement || onChangeEvent.target).files[0]);
        });
      }
    };
  }
})();
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: in that case you have to point it instead at a PHP script which queries the mySQL database and returns the relevant data in the desired format

Comment: I see... let's say i name it "data.php", how then should I insert it so it is (pre)loaded when I open the main HTML/PHP page? (without selecting it?)

Comment: I should think you just replace "radar.csv" with "data.php". As long as the output of the PHP script is in CSV format, I doubt the browser should notice any difference - it just makes a HTTP request to that URL (data.php) instead of the other URL (radar.csv) and gets the response. As long as it can read the response, it should be fine.